# $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ as groups.

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, direct-product

If $\alpha: \Bbb{Z}_{5} \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{26})$ is some group homomorphism, how do we show that $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ as groups? I'm pretty sure that they *are* isomorphic as groups, but I'm struggling to prove it.

By definition of semidirect product, $\Bbb{Z}_{26}$ is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5}$. My idea is to show that $\Bbb{Z}_{5}$ is also a normal subgroup of this semidirect product, because then we can fairly easily construct the desired direct product and show that they're isomorphic as groups. But it's proving a *lot* harder to prove that than I thought it would be.

I've also tried brute-forcing an isomorphism, such as $\varphi: \Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ defined by $(n, a) \mapsto (n, a)$, but that has been... less than fruitful.

This is actually a part of something bigger I'm working on, but I think understanding this might help me understand the more general case. I think the biggest issue is that the specifics of $\alpha$ are unknown.

Edit: Something I forgot to include. My last idea is to show that $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ is cyclic, since $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$ is cyclic. But without knowing what $\alpha$ is, it's pretty difficult to find a generating element of $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{26})|=\varphi(26)=12$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler phi function.

By the First Isomorphism Theorem and Lagrange's Theorem, $|\Bbb{Z}_5:\ker \alpha|$ divides $|\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{26})|=12$. This is only possible when $\ker\alpha=\Bbb{Z}_5$, that is, $\alpha$ is the trivial automorphism. Therefore $\Bbb{Z}_{26} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{5} \cong \Bbb{Z}_{26} \times \Bbb{Z}_{5}$.

Comment: @bananacreamsalad The map $\mathbb Z/5 \longrightarrow Aut(\mathbb Z/26)$ is surjective onto its image, which is a subgroup of the codomain. Apply Langrange's theorem to that image.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I think First Isomorphism Theorem is still required to show that $|\alpha(\Bbb{Z}_5)|$ divides $|\Bbb{Z}_5|$.

Comment: Yup I agree. I didn't make that clear in my comment. What I meant to get across to OP was to apply the first isomorphism theorem onto the image of $\alpha$ because they were confused about surjectivity, though it seems they've deleted their comment anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In case one hasn't got at hand the result $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{26})\right|=\varphi(26)$, the following group action argument can bypass it.

If a group $G$ acts on another group $H$ (by automorphisms), then, for every $g\in G$:
$$\operatorname{Fix}(g)\le H \tag 1$$
where $\operatorname{Fix}(g):=\{h\in H\mid \alpha_g(h)=h\}$.

If $G$ and $H$ are both finite, say $G=\{g_1,\dots,g_{|G|}\}$ and $H=\{h_1,\dots,h_{|H|}\}$, then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{|H|}\left|\operatorname{Stab}(h_i)\right|=\sum_{j=1}^{|G|}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g_j)\right| \tag 2$$
and (by Burnside's counting lemma):
$$|G|\text{ divides both sides of }(2) \tag 3$$
Moreover, by $(1)$, ***all the summands in the RHS of $(2)$ divide $|H|$***.

In particular, for $G=\Bbb Z_5$ and $H=\Bbb Z_{26}$, *if* a nontrivial action $\alpha$ exists, then $\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g_{\bar j})\right|\ne 26$ and $\left|\operatorname{Stab}(h_{\bar i})\right|=1$, for some $\bar j\in \{1,\dots,5\}$ and $\bar i\in\{1,\dots,26\}$. Then $(2)$ yields:
$$k+5(26-k)=l_1+2l_2+13l_3+26[5-(l_1+l_2+l_3)] \tag4$$
where $1\le k\le 25$ (the rightmost inequality is because $0_{\Bbb Z_{26}}$ *is fixed* by all the elements of $\Bbb Z_{5}$) and $1\le l_1+l_2+l_3\le 4$ (the rightmost inequality is because $0_{\Bbb Z_5}$ *does fix* all the elements of $\Bbb Z_{26}$). By rearranging $(4)$:
$$4k=25l_1+24l_2+13l_3 \tag5$$
But since $5\mid k$ (by $(3)$ and $(4)$), from $(5)$ follows:
$$20m=25l_1+24l_2+13l_3 \tag6$$
for some $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $l_1+l_2+l_3\in\{1,2,3,4
\}$. The only solution $(m,l_1,l_2,l_3)$ of $(6)$ is:
$$(m,l_1,l_2,l_3)=(5,4,0,0)$$
and hence the only solution $(k,l_1,l_2,l_3)$ of $(4)$ is:
$$(k,l_1,l_2,l_3)=(25,4,0,0)$$
This means that all the $25$ nontrivial elements of $\Bbb Z_{26}$ have trivial stabilizer: contradiction, because $13$ is the only element of order $2$ in $\Bbb Z_{26}$, and hence every automorphism fixes it.

Therefore, there isn't any such a nontrivial action, and $\Bbb Z_5\ltimes\Bbb Z_{26}=$ $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_{26}$.